Messages not reaching RabbitMQ queue when sent from ESP32 via MQTT, but can be consumed live
I am running a script on an ESP32 board which is attempting to publish data to a RabbitMQ server using the PubSubClient library.
The client is defined on the ESP board as follows:
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

The client is initialised (where mqtt_server is the server's address and mqtt_port is 1883, the default MQTT port:
client.setServer(mqtt_server, mqtt_port);
The client is connected to using (where the username and password are defined appropriately):
client.connect("ESP32Client", mqtt_user, mqtt_pass)
client.loop(); is run at the start of the loop() function.`
I'm publishing using these lines (where jsonBuffer is of type char and consists of a serialised Json doc):
client.publish("device/status", jsonBuffer, true)
client.publish("sensors/data", jsonBuffer, true)
My RabbitMQ server has the queue mqtt_queue with the following bindings:

When I look at the RabbitMQ online GUI while the ESP code is running the queue shows no messages are being published there.
The queue has the following properties:
features:       durable:true
expires:    2419200000
max-length: 10000
queue-mode: lazy
queue-version:  2

However, when I run the following Python script, it gets every packet as it is sent, and can write it to file, meaning they are definitely leaving the board.
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# Define the callback for connection
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to broker")
        client.subscribe("sensors/data")
        client.subscribe("device/status")
    else:
        print("Connection failed with code ", rc)

# Define the callback for receiving messages
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    payload = message.payload.decode()
    print(f"Message received from topic {message.topic}: {payload}")
    
    if message.topic == "sensors/data":
        with open("sensor_data.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(f"{payload}\n")
    elif message.topic == "device/status":
        with open("device_status.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(f"{payload}\n")

# Create an MQTT client instance
client = mqtt.Client()

# Set username and password
client.username_pw_set("example_username", password='example_password')

# Connect to the MQTT broker
client.connect("example_server.com", 1883)

# Attach callback functions
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

# Start the network loop
client.loop_forever()


I sent messages using MQTT PubSubClient from an ESP32 board, expecting them to be put in an AMQP queue, but they were not.

Is this a python question or an ESP32 Arduino/C++ question? If the problem is with the Arduino code, then you should show your code from ESP32 in Arduino(which not work), not the code in python (which work).
